# Error aleatorio en Arduino

Tags: python, arduino

**Edicion 1:**
Parecía que el fallo se trataba de un fallo de cableado, el cual fallaba y cada cierto tiempo realiza un falso contacto.
Después de desconectar el **pin 0** y no tener nada conectado sigue realizando el mismo fallo.
**Fin edición 1**

Tengo un pequeño error un poco tonto(eso espero) el cual me salta **al cargar mi código algunas veces**, otras veces funciona perfectamente. Por ese motivo creo que debe ser algo en lo que no me he percatado.

En este caso estoy conectando un **monedero electrónico** a un **Arduino UNO** por el **Pin digital 2**.

El error se presenta cada vez que cargo el código en el Arduino y o lo reinicio.
Según le viene cuando acaba de cargar puede indicar en pantalla **Credit: 0.00**(que es lo que debería) o puede poner **Credit: 0.10**.
Si todas las veces pusiese 0.10 aun podría entender que el fallo es la primera conexión con el monedero, pero al variar cada vez no se descartar el fallo.

Os dejo mi código por si veis algo que yo no consigo localizar:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd (0x27, 20, 4);//en este caso una pantalla de 20x4



int pindeentrada = 0; //Monedero conectado a pin 2 (pin 2 es igual a 0)
volatile float montoTotal = 0.00;//variable que contara el monto
int deteccionDeCoin = 0;//Detector del Monedero electronico

void setup(){
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);//Start Serial Communication
  attachInterrupt(pindeentrada, insercionCredito, RISING);
  Wire.begin();//PANTALLA
  lcd.begin(20, 4);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);lcd.print("Credit: "); lcd.print(montoTotal);//FIN PANTALLA
}

void insercionCredito(){ //Esta funcion es la encargada de leer los pulsos del monedero
  deteccionDeCoin = 1; //Actualizacion del detector del monnedero
}

void loop(){ //Bucle que actualiza el arduino
  if(deteccionDeCoin == 1){ //Comprobacion del detector del monedero
    montoTotal = montoTotal + 0.10; //esta variable suma en el monto total
    lcd.clear();//pantalla
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Credit: "); lcd.print(montoTotal);
    deteccionDeCoin = 0; //Reset del detector
  }
}
```

En cualquier caso muchas gracias por tomaros el tiempo de leerlo y cualquier ayuda sera agradecida.

Comment: No hay problema en el código, el error debe estar en la conexión física del pin 0, si no esta correctamente conectada a tierra o VCC generara que alentadamente se dispare la interrupción, valida que los pines estén alineados en el [software y hardware](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/)

Comment: @ivanfajardo Cierto, deje el sistema durante 2h activo y llego a 0.70, pero he revisado todas las conexiones y no encuentro el fallo. Tengo el monedero conectado a una fuente de pc por positivo y negativo. El cable de **coin** al pin 0. No se si podrías darme algún consejo.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas el pin 2 sin hacer un `pinMode()` primero?

Comment: Hace falta el diagrama de cableado y las especificaciones del monedero, para revisar el datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta era más compleja de lo que podría pensar.

Después de reformar toda la instalación eléctrica de la casa y del edificio dejó de producirse este problema. Seguramente sería algún tipo de retorno eléctrico, ya que ahora los leds del Arduino no tintinean como lo hacían antes.

(Las reformas no las hice para solucionar el problema, que ya veo algún gracioso haciendo la broma...)